My Audi A6 2007 has a flat battery and is dead locked the key fob won't unlock it as it battery is dead and the key entry doesn't work
Need to get power to battery so i can use fob

The battery is in the boot/trunk. Can't you use the key blade to open it? Isn't there a slot for the key blade visible if you look upwards from underneath?

Is there a key blade in your remote to unlock the driver's door? If the lock cylinder is seized, try lock lube. Other than trying to manually pull the hood release under the front grille from the bottom, looking up, you may need a locksmith with air bladder to wedge open a window to use a tool to unlock a door.

Some key fobs have a blade that slides out. These tend to be vehicles without a physical ignition lock.

The key entry doesn't work on either door?

@WeatherVane off the top of my head I think an '07 A6 will be the older style "flip" key rather than than the hidden blade of the later models. Of course there's no guarantee that the physical lock on the door is in particularly good working order. Lack of use can make them anything from a bit stiff (some penetrating fluid might help) to full on seized up.

No boot key hole entry, only driver side door has key hole but key doesn't unlock it never has yes it's a flip key

Well you cant get in without breaking stuff .If you can charge the battery then you can hop in normally because the central locking receiver and soleniod will open the door .You can connect the neg black clip of your battery charger to the car body somewhere because all cars these days are neg earth . Now the pos red lead can be clipped onto the starter motor when you get under the car and have a look or use Dr google for drawings .The battery always goes direct to the starter motor via a heavy easy to find cable .Now you can connect your charger and you should see some current on the dial ,Wait a hour or 2 and hop in with your fob.

Ok I done exactly that had power to the car as the lights inside the car come on the dash so I can see its getting power to it but the key would unlock fob won't unlock it.. I put power to the starter motor but I didn't leave the charger on it for an hour or 2  it keep flashing red on the charger saying to much voltage should I just leave it on it for an hour or 2 or do I need a different charger
